#  How to select most Ordered Products in SQL Server?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to grab Top 10 most Ordered product by customer...
Im counting how many lines that this product have been ordered .

Sample data:

```
 ProdName
    A
    B
    C 
    A
    B

    Count A=2 ,B=2,C=1
```

Here's my code

```
SELECT TOP 10  ProdName,COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
   FROM SampleTable
   GROUP BY ProdName 
   ORDER  BY OrderCount,ProdName
```

Ive done this in other database using LIMIT 10..
but here in SQL server the result of that query is the bottom record's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the highest values first, use a [DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) sort:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ProdName, COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY ProdName 
ORDER BY OrderCount DESC, ProdName
```

Comment: Thanks, how come I did not arrive with this solution, sorry  my bad.